# PictureBox.LoadAsync Bitmap.Clone resulting in: Object is currently used elsewhere

Tags: c#

I'm trying to start a process once a data is received from a serialPort, the process is:

- Receive the "shoot" string in serialPort1;
- Run the function "shoot" to load an image to a pictureBox;
- Once the picture was loaded (loadAsync), clone a region of this image to another pictureBox;

If I manually click in the button1, all works great, but if I use the serialPort trigger I'm getting an "Object is currently used elsewhere" during the pictureBox region clone step...

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shoot();
}

public void shoot()
{
    pictureBox1.LoadAsync(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.jpg")[0].ToString());
}

private void PictureBox1_LoadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string[] init = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().Split('x');
    string[] end = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString().Split('x');
    Bitmap Bmp = ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).Clone(new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(init[0]), Convert.ToInt32(init[1]), Convert.ToInt32(end[0]), Convert.ToInt32(end[1])), pictureBox1.Image.PixelFormat);
    pictureBox2.Image = Bmp;
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkData(serialPort1.ReadLine());
}

private void checkData(String data)
{
    if (data.Contains("shoot"))
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(shoot);
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the exception in this line:

```cs
Bitmap Bmp = ((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image).Clone(new Rectangle(Convert.ToInt32(init[0]), Convert.ToInt32(init[1]), Convert.ToInt32(end[0]), Convert.ToInt32(end[1])), pictureBox1.Image.PixelFormat);
```

How can I fix it?
Thank you!!!

**Edited:**

It was fixed by adding the this.BeginInvoke as informed by **Hans Passant**:

**From**

```cs
public void shoot()
{
    pictureBox1.LoadAsync(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.jpg")[0].ToString());
}
```

**To**

```cs
public void shoot()
{
   pictureBox1.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
   {
      pictureBox1.LoadAsync(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath, "*.jpg")[0].ToString());
   }));
}
```

Comment: Any code that touches a Winforms control, like PictureBox, must run on the UI thread.  Use this.BeginInvoke() in the checkData() method.

Comment: Thank you Hans!!! This is a new concept for me! It works!